# A cleaner way to select by multiple possible attribute values?

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors

Is there a possibility in jQuery to select by multiple possible attribute values without having to use a comma separated list of selectors.

So in stead of:

```
#list1 > option[value="1"], #list1 > option[value="2"], etc
```

Something like:

```
#list1 > option[value="1"|value="2"], etc
```

Comment: The closest would be `jQuery('[attribute*="value"]')`. Attribute contains value selector.

Comment: @JohnP: hmmm, I was really hoping for exact values, as per this question, and my somewhat ugly answer to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471777/showing-hiding-the-next-div-on-mouseover-of-the-previous-div

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Not that I know of. The *cleanest* way I can think of doing this is to first select using the common elements across all items, then just `.find()` or `.filter()` the OR values out.

Something like

```
$('#list1 > option[value]')
    .filter('[value="1"],[value="2"]')
    ;
```

Comment: ... or perhaps extend jQuery with your own chain wrapper function. :D

Comment: Ah yes, that's not so bad actually (referring to your answer, not the comment ;-)). Upvote from me. :)

Comment: Not saying the comment is bad BTW. But not that well versed in jQuery to even know what you're talking about exactly, let alone know how to hack it together. :)

Comment: @fireeyedboy ~ ah, don't worry about it. :D It'd make for some good reading though when you find the time, so this is basically the gist of it: http://me.lt/4xl6P . Of course, better documentation over on the jQuery site itself. :D

Comment: ah yes, I see what you mean now. I've seen that before in various plugins. I'm afraid hacking together proposed functionality of my question would be pretty tricky though. ;-) I don't think I could be bothered to do it, seeing your answer is pretty damn clean already as far as I'm concerned. One could probably win a few milliseconds with such an implementation. But I just don't care enough. :-P Thanks for the link though. Useful nonetheless!

Answer (score 2):

You can make a custom jQuery function like this:

```
$.fn.filterAttrVals = function (attr, vals) {
    var filter = '[' + attr + '="' + vals.split(',').join('"],[' + attr + '="') + '"]';
    return this.filter(filter);
};
```

For your example you could use it in the following way:

```
$('#list1 > option').filterAttrVals('value','1,2');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
var valuesNeeded = [1,2,etc];

$('#list1 > option').filter(function( index ) {
    return valuesNeeded.indexOf($(this).attr('value')) != -1;
});
```