# Showing/hiding the next div on mouseover of the previous div

Tags: php, jquery

This is my php code:

```
echo '<div class="code" rel="$url">$title</div>
    <div class="tip">Copy and open site</div>';
```

the above is a loop's echo result. Namely, there maybe 0->n like the following html structure

```
<div class="code" rel="....">...</div>
        <div class="tip">Copy and open site</div>
```

Now, supposed there are 6 results like the above, I want to use jQuery to get when I put the mouse hover on the first `<div class="code" rel="....">...</div>` the only first tip div will show. When I move the mouse out, the div will be hidden.

I think using jQuery alone can't get that effect. There must be some php added to the code, but I don't know how to do that?

Comment: i think 
$('.code').mouseover(
function(){this.next().show()},
function(){this.next().hide()
});

Comment: @Arun: test it in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and post that as an answer :)

Comment: how to make the default tip div in hide state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( 'div.code' ).mouseover( function() {
    $( this ).next( 'div.tip' ).show();
} );

$( 'div.code' ).mouseout( function() {
    $( this ).next( 'div.tip' ).hide();
} );
```

**Edit based on your first comment:**

There's a few possibilities:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {  // added document ready for completeness
    $( 'div.code' ).mouseover( function() {
        $( this ).next( 'div.tip' ).show();
    } );
    $( 'div.code' ).mouseout( function() {
        $( this ).next( 'div.tip' ).hide();
    } );

    // this is a way after declaring previous stuff:
    $( 'div.code' ).trigger( 'mouseout' );

    // or simply do:
    $( 'div.tip' ).hide();
} );
```

Comment: how to make the default tip div  in hide state?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to refer to the tip DIV more specifically than just a class selector.
Something like...

```
  <div id="link1" class="code" rel="....">...</div>
    <div id="tip1" class="tip">Copy and open site</div>
```

And then have the hover property of #link1 point to your JQuery display code.

Comment: Nah, jQuery can find the next element or the next element with a given class name.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm a bit old-skool myself... pre js-library.