# jQuery attribute selector for multiple values

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the following html, is there a selector that allows me to get both based on `type`?

```
<input type="text"  />
<input type="button"  />
```

```
$('input[type=text || button]'); //for example, double pipes as an OR does not work
```

I went through the docs, but I couldn't find anything on the ability to use logical operators or a means of providing a matching list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery: cleaner way to select by multple possible attribute values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471775/jquery-cleaner-way-to-select-by-multple-possible-attribute-values)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This should help:

```
$('input[type="text"], input[type="button"]');
```

Comment: Is there really no better solution to this? I was afraid this might be a little performance waisting compared to a "value1|value2" solution, but there's no other way in CSS3 either, so I started searching. Well, I just hope jQuery has done it's best in terms of optimizations.

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
$("input:text, input:button");
```