# jQuery/JavaScript Selector OR ||

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery attribute selector for multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005361/jquery-attribute-selector-for-multiple-values)

I have this

```
$('input:radio[name=foo]').change(function() {
    blah();
});

$('input:radio[name=bar]').change(function() {
    blah();
});
```

Can I do something like this?

```
$('input:radio[name=foo||bar]').change(function() {
    blah();
});
```

what If I had another one?

```
$('input:radio[name=foo||bar||foobar]').change(function() {
    blah();
});
```

I can't use class which would be ideal as this is a custom framework (not mine) that 
generates the HTML which is overriding my class. Also there is no id selector available
just the name attribute. I think I'm stuck doing separate functions but wanted to pose the question to see if anyone can think outside the box on this one.

Note: this project uses jQuery 1.3.2 and I can't upgrade just yet. And before you say anything, yeah I'm with you on upgrading...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no 'or' character, but you can use multiple selectors - you just separate them by commas:

```
$('input:radio[name=foo], input:radio[name=bar]').change(function() {
    blah();
});
```

Or better yet, use a class selector as this is exactly what they were designed for.

Comment: I did not know you could comma delimiter, thanks! Learned something new

Comment: +1 did not know you could do that either. good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't a simple selector for `or` within `[attr]` selectors. You can use a [comma (`,`)](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to separate your selections:

```
$('input:radio[name=foo], input:radio[name=bar]').change(...);
```

Or if your selection happens to be longer, you can use `$.fn.filter`:

```
$('#foo #bar #baz .fizz .buzz input:radio').filter('[name=foo], [name=bar]').change(...);
```

I recommend reviewing the entire list of [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `$()` function uses CSS selectors (nearly all of [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) plus a few of [its own](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)). Their syntax has nothing whatsoever to do with JavaScript's logical operators.

Neither CSS3 nor jQuery offer a "match any of these", so you use a [selector group](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping) instead:

```
$('input:radio[name=foo], input:radio[name=bar], input:radio[name=foobar]').change(function() {
    blah();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is adding a new filter for regex:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Then you can do something like

```
$('input:radio:regex(name, ^(foo|bar|baz)$)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed solution does work on newer versions of jQuery. You can chain filter onto your query, though ...

```
$('input:radio').filter("[name=foo],[name=bar]").change(function() {
   blah();
});
```

View and play with the jsfiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/NAgv5/1/