# jQuery multiple data-role selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery attribute selector for multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005361/jquery-attribute-selector-for-multiple-values)

Suppose that I have the following:

```
<a href="#" class="result-name" data-role="1" data-obj-id="15">Obj 15</a>
<a href="#" class="result-name" data-role="3" data-obj-id="19">Obj 19</a>
<a href="#" class="result-name" data-role="2" data-obj-id="20">Obj 20</a>
```

Right now, I'm doing something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.result-name', function() {
  var objId = $(this).data('obj-id');
  // do some ajax call...
});
```

Now, if I want to call add this behavior only in the links with role 1 or 3, and I want to do that in the selector, how can I do that?

I tried:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.result-name[data-role=1|3]', function() { //...
```

without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use comma to attach event to multiple elements

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.result-name[data-role=1], a.result-name[data-role=3]', function() { //...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RSwMw/2/

Also you can use `NotEqual` selector `!=`

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.result-name[data-role!=2]', function() { //...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RSwMw/1/

Comment: good suggestion, but, if I add more roles, I get the same issue... so it will not fit in my case. Thank you anyway.

Comment: anyway, your answer was the most complete. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to separate the selector into two matches:

```
.on('click', 'a.result-name[data-role=1], a.result-name[data-role=3]')
```

Or possibly make the selection from within the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for this: http://jsfiddle.net/HXq9Q/

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.result-name[data-role=3],[data-role=1]', function () {
 // action here
});
```

Comment: This will attach event on ANY element which has `data-role=1` attribute.