# Hide table columns on page load and make them appear using checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle, visibility

I've been searching for a solution to my problem and I'm sure it is a simple one, but I am new to javascript and jquery. Well, I have a table and some of its columns should be hidden on page load and then make them visible using checkboxes. I found a jquery script that handles that but just with one column. In my case, I need 6 columns to appear hidden. 
This is the Jquery script I'm tweaking:

```
$(function(){
    $(':checkbox').on('change', function(){
        $('th, td', 'tr').filter(':nth-child(' + $(this).attr('rel') + ')').toggle();
    });
    $(":checkbox[rel='2']").change(); //this line will hide the 2nd column when the DOM is ready. Don't forget to start the corresponding hidden columns' checkboxes WITHOUT checked="checked"
});
```

I tried adding more rel values, but it did not work as expected.

```
 $(":checkbox[rel='2, 3, 4, 5, 6']").change();
```

This is the url to the JSFiddle with my working example: http://jsfiddle.net/k7zQ2/

Hope you can help me!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005361/jquery-attribute-selector-for-multiple-values) you'll have to specify each selector, not just the `rel` values. Something like this would hide columns 2 and 3 initially:

```
$(":checkbox[rel='2'], :checkbox[rel='3']").change();
```

If you were to specify multiple `rel` attribute values in your selector you wouldn't be looking for elements with either of those values, but BOTH of those values - as explained [here in the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/).

Other than that it looks like your other checkboxes are working fine you just need to change the `rel` values to something other than 2. Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7zQ2/1/).

Comment: A big thankyou Goose. I'll test it tomorrow but so far it seems it works great. Thanks again