# Function variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, variables

This is pretty simple, but I need to be able to toggle showing columns in a table.

The idea is to have a function that will take the name of the column (all the rows have the same data-field in the same column) and hide it, adjusting the width of the table as it goes.

Using Chrome's inspector, I came up with a simple proof of concept

```
$('[data-id="column"],[data-field="column"]').toggle()
```

After running the above, I need to adjust the width of the element plus / minus 4 pixels for the table to fit correctly - The table renders a white box on the right hand side where the column(s). This is just a proof of concept and the actual width will be stored in a variable that will be manipulated to allow multiple columns to be hidden.

```
$(".oe_list_content").width($(window).width()+/-4)
```

I made a simple function to come up with the initial idea, but when I run the function, it returns undefined and doesn't make the changes. I'm fairly certain that it can, but is the jQuery selector not able to take a function variable?

```
function rowToggle(row){
    // Verify the rows even exist in the DOM
    if($('[data-id="'+row+'"]').length){
        $('[data-id="'+row+'"]','[data-field="'+row+'"]').toggle();
        if($('[data-id="'+row+'"]').is(':hidden')){
            $(".table").width($(window).width()+4);
        }else{
            $(".table").width($(window).width()-4);
        }
    }
}
```

This really seems like a variable problem because

```
var row = "column";
$('[data-id="'+ row +'"]').toggle();
```

doesn't actually toggle the field. Am I missing something?

Comment: could you post html you are working with ?

Comment: `var row = "column"; `    I hope you realize that is weird. Also if you want a function to return something you must specify a `return` statement.

Comment: The selector is just a string, concatenating a variable will work as well. [For example](https://jsfiddle.net/4c9esfyx/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line
`$('[data-id="'+row+'"]','[data-field="'+row+'"]').toggle();`

Should be:
`$('[data-id="'+row+'"],[data-field="'+row+'"]').toggle();`

It's a single selector string. Not two strings separated by a comma as you had it.

Further reference to this issue: **[jQuery attribute selector for multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9005361/1046690)**