# jQuery multiple attribute selector with logic OR, shortcuts?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

> Select all elements with `data-toggle` attribute no matter value and with
>   (`href="#myModal"` or `data-target="#myModal"`).

I've used this:

```
$('[data-toggle][href="#myModal"], [data-toggle][data-target="#myModal"]');
```

Not DRY. Is there any simple method or function to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471775/a-cleaner-way-to-select-by-multiple-possible-attribute-values

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Maybe something like that?

```
$("[data-toggle]").filter("[href='#myModal'],[data-target='#myModal']");
```