# Select multiple options to remove

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to remove several options from a dropdown ui-combobox list.

Is this "allowed" or is there something similar I can do?

This works:

```
$("#select option[value='51']").remove();
```

This does not work:

```
$("#select option[value='51''127']").remove();
```

Nor does this work:

```
$("#select option[value='51, 127']").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can use this one instead

```
$("#select option[value='51'],#select option[value='127']").remove();
```

check a working example
http://jsfiddle.net/abletech/W4Km8/

Update 1
another method as stated here [A cleaner way to select by multiple possible attribute values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471775/a-cleaner-way-to-select-by-multiple-possible-attribute-values)

you can use

`$("#select option[value]").filter('[value="51"],[value="127"]');`

update 2

About that 50 column method , okay we have to create a function for that

```
    function removeMultipleOptions(removeList){
var removeString='';
for(var i=0;i<removeList.length - 2 ;i++){
removeString += "#select option[value='"+removeList[i]+"'],";
}
removeString += "#select option[value='"+removeList[i+1]+"']"; //no comma
$(removeString).remove();
}
removeMultipleOptions(['51','127',....]);
```

this is considered a bad practice of hard-coding. But no one to judge our code.

Comment: I see, yea it's a possibility. I've got about 50~ options I want to remove though :P

Comment: That's hard-coding mate XD !!  but there is always a solution

Comment: The values are stored in sql, so I made a stored procedure that generated the ID's i needed then added "],[value="(number goes here)

Stored the query result as a variable and then did it like this 


   ------------------  $("#select option[value]").filter('[value="<cfoutput>#variable#</cfoutput>"]); ---------------------------------------------


It's not pretty nor very practical I think. I'm trying to find a much more efficient way of doing it :P (using coldfusion if you didnt notice)

Comment: Well if all the options are in the database fiter them within a query

Answer (score 0):

If you can first form an array of all the values to be removed, then it would be convenient and fairly efficient to do the removal as follows :

```
var values = ['51', '127', ...];

$("#select option").filter(function(i, opt) {
    return $.inArray(opt.value, values) > -1;
}).remove();
```

Explanation: `$("#select option")` finds *all* the options nodes as efficiently as possible in jQuery. After that, the filtering is performed totally in javascript without the need to discover more nodes. Finally `.remove()` performs the removal of all remaining nodes that survived the filter.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4cw3hxpu/)**